# How to expect the number of dom in karma+enzyme

Tags: karma-jasmine, enzyme

I follow this link 'https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md' to write an unit test as below:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
describe('Question Test Suite', () => {

  it('should render one <TextField/> components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<QuestionForm />, { context: {router: {} }});
    expect(wrapper.find(TextField)).to.have.length(1);
  });

});
```

when run the test case I got below error:

```
TypeError: expect(...).length is not a function
TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
```

What wrong with my test case? Is there anything I am missing there?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong.The below syntax should work fine.

```
expect(wrapper.find('TextField').length).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: I tried that and it works. I just wander why my syntax is wrong. I followed the enzyme document. If it is wrong, where can I find the official api document for how to use expect.

Comment: to.have.length is part of the chai syntax.You can use that if you are using chai.toBe() or toEqual() is part of the expect syntax. So it depends on what you're using for assertions

Comment: I am new to karma and js unit test. I didn't find anywhere I use chai or not. Could you let me know what syntax I can set?

Comment: > I tried that and it works. I just wander why my syntax is wrong. I followed the enzyme document. If it is wrong, where can I find the official api document for how to use expect. 

The to.have.length call just takes the param in expect and looks for a .length property. eg
```
expect([1,2,3]).to.have.length(3);
expect({a: 1, length: 6}).to.have.length(6);

//fails
//expect(wrapper.find(TextField)).to.have.length(1);
wrapper.find(TextField).length; //length doesn't exist
```